# Calling the right constructor

Tags: c++, templates, constructor

I have a class X with two constructors defined as follows:

```
template <typename T>
class X {
  template <typename U>      
  X(U& u) {
   // some logic
  }

  X(const Y<T>& y) {
    // some other logic
  }
};
```

Class Y has a static method which return objects of type Y.

```
template <typename T>
class Y {
  static Y<T> myStaticMethod(const T& t) {
    // some logic
  }
};
```

Now if I try, the following code:

```
const Y<double>& obj = Y<double>::myStaticMethod(1.0);
X<double> xObj = new X<double>(obj);
```

The constructor with the double template T and U gets called with T = double which is expected but U = `Y<double>*` which is rather unexpected.

I wanted that the second constructor of X got called but it doesn't happen. Moreover, why is obj converted to a pointer when I have called the constructor with a reference?

Comment: Your constructor template is too greedy, it says "any conversion from any lvalue is allowed" and then may fail to actually perform this conversion. `new` is not necessary in C++ to define objects (and wrong here as far as I can see).

Answer (score 2):

Consider your line:

```
X<double> xObj = new X<double>(obj);
```

This tells the compiler to take the results of the new expression, and
convert them to an `X<double>`.  The type of the results of the new
expression is `X<double>*`; the only constructor for `X<double>` which
can be called with a pointer is `template <typename T> X:X(U& )`.
Except that it can't be called either, since it would require binding an
rvalue to a non-const reference.  But some compilers are broken, and
allow it anyway.

As written, the code shouldn't compile, but if it does, it should call the constructor of `X<double>` twice.

Answer (score 1):

Take that line apart and put them into two lines.

```
X<double>* xObjPtr = new X<double>(obj);
X<double> xObj = xObjPtr;
```

Does it make sense now why the compiler is trying to invoke:

```
template <typename U> X(U& u) {}
```

with `U == X<double>*`

Comment: But he said that `U == Y*` instead. Maybe a typo on his part and he really meant `X<double>*`?